# Wrong path lines in d3 tree diagram when dragging

Tags: javascript, d3.js, path, tree, drag-and-drop

I use d3.js library. On dragging nodes the path lines are being drawn improperly. I have a diagonal radial d3 tree diagram but it seems like the lines are set like in a horizontal tree diagram. Also the dragging node is not just under the cursor and its position is getting even worse when I zoom.
I rebuild my code to paste it into jsfiddle so the panning and zooming functions are not working.

Here's the working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t3yqdvtg/

```
var jsondata = {
    "name": "AUT-1",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "PUB-1","children": [
                {"name": "AUT-11","children": [
                    {"name": "AFF-111"},
                    {"name": "AFF-112"}
                ]},
                {"name": "AUT-12","children": [
                    {"name": "AFF-121"}
                ]},
                {"name": "AUT-13","children": [
                    {"name": "AFF-131"},
                    {"name": "AFF-132"}
                ]},
                {"name": "AUT-14","children": [
                    {"name": "AFF-141"}
                ]}
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "PUB-2","children": [
                {"name": "AUT-21"},
                {"name": "AUT-22"},
                {"name": "AUT-23"},
                {"name": "AUT-24"},
                {"name": "AUT-25"},
                {"name": "AUT-26"},
                {"name": "AUT-27"},
                {"name": "AUT-28","children":[
                    {"name": "AFF-281"},
                    {"name": "AFF-282"},
                    {"name": "AFF-283"},
                    {"name": "AFF-284"},
                    {"name": "AFF-285"},
                    {"name": "AFF-286"}
                ]}
            ]
        },
        {"name": "PUB-3"},
        {
            "name": "PUB-4","children": [
                {"name": "AUT-41"},
                {"name": "AUT-42"},
                {"name": "AUT-43","children": [
                    {"name": "AFF-431"},
                    {"name": "AFF-432"},
                    {"name": "AFF-433"},
                    {"name": "AFF-434","children":[
                        {"name": "ADD-4341"},
                        {"name": "ADD-4342"}
                    ]}
                ]},
                {"name": "AUT-44"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "PUB-5","children": [
                {"name": "AUT-51","children":[
                    {"name": "AFF-511"},
                    {"name": "AFF-512"},
                    {"name": "AFF-513"},
                    {"name": "AFF-514"},
                    {"name": "AFF-515"},
                    {"name": "AFF-516"}
                ]},
                {"name": "AUT-52"},
                {"name": "AUT-53"},
                {"name": "AUT-54"},
                {"name": "AUT-55","children":[
                    {"name": "AFF-551"},
                    {"name": "AFF-552"},
                    {"name": "AFF-553"},
                    {"name": "AFF-554"}
                ]},
                {"name": "AUT-56"},
                {"name": "AUT-57"},
                {"name": "AUT-58"},
                {"name": "AUT-59"},
                {"name": "AUT-591"},
                {"name": "AUT-592"},
                {"name": "AUT-593"},
                {"name": "AUT-594"},
                {"name": "AUT-595"},
                {"name": "AUT-596"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "PUB-6","children": [
                {"name": "AUT-61","children":[
                    {"name": "AFF-611"},
                    {"name": "AFF-612"},
                    {"name": "AFF-613"},
                    {"name": "AFF-614","children":[
                        {"name": "ADD-6141"},
                        {"name": "ADD-6142"}
                    ]}
                ]},
                {"name": "AUT-62"},
                {"name": "AUT-63"},
                {"name": "AUT-64"},
                {"name": "AUT-65"},
                {"name": "AUT-66"},
                {"name": "AUT-67"},
                {"name": "AUT-68"},
                {"name": "AUT-69"}
            ]
        }
    ]
};

// Calculate total nodes, max label length
var totalNodes = 0;
var maxLabelLength = 0;
// variables for drag/drop
var selectedNode = null;
var draggingNode = null;
// panning variables
var panSpeed = 200;
var panBoundary = 20; // Within 20px from edges will pan when dragging.
// Misc. variables
var i = 0;
var duration = 300; // Duration of animations
var root;
// size of the diagram
var viewerWidth = $(document).width() - 10;
var viewerHeight = $(document).height() - 45;

// Diagram layour
var tree = d3.layout.tree()
.size([360, viewerWidth])
.separation(function(a, b) { return (a.parent == b.parent ? 5 : 10) / a.depth; }); // distance between nodes of the same parent or on the same level

// define a d3 diagonal projection for use by the node paths later on.
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial()
.projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI]; });

// define the baseSvg, attaching a class for styling and the zoomListener
var baseSvg = d3.select("#tree-container").append("svg")
.attr("width", viewerWidth)
.attr("height", viewerHeight)
.attr("class", "overlay")

// Define the root
root = jsondata;
root.x0 = viewerHeight ;
root.y0 = viewerWidth ;


// Append a group which holds all nodes and which the zoom Listener can act upon.
//var svgGroup = baseSvg.append("g");

// A recursive helper function for performing some setup by walking through all nodes
function visit(parent, visitFn, childrenFn) {
    if (!parent) return;

    visitFn(parent);

    var children = childrenFn(parent);
    if (children) {
        var count = children.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            visit(children[i], visitFn, childrenFn);
        }
    }
}

// Call visit function to establish maxLabelLength
visit(jsondata, function(d) {
    totalNodes++;
    maxLabelLength = Math.max(d.name.length, maxLabelLength);
}, function(d) {    
    return d.children && d.children.length > 0 ? d.children : null;
}
     );

// sort the tree according to the node names
function sortTree() {
    tree.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.name.toLowerCase() < a.name.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
    });
}
// Sort the tree initially incase the JSON isn't in a sorted order.
sortTree();

// Panning function
function pan(domNode, direction) {
    var speed = panSpeed;
    if (panTimer) {
        clearTimeout(panTimer);
        translateCoords = d3.transform(baseSvg.attr("transform"));
        if (direction == 'left' || direction == 'right') {
            translateX = direction == 'left' ? translateCoords.translate[0] + speed : translateCoords.translate[0] - speed;
            translateY = translateCoords.translate[1];
        } else if (direction == 'up' || direction == 'down') {
            translateX = translateCoords.translate[0];
            translateY = direction == 'up' ? translateCoords.translate[1] + speed : translateCoords.translate[1] - speed;
        }
        scaleX = translateCoords.scale[0];
        scaleY = translateCoords.scale[1];
        scale = zoomListener.scale();
        baseSvg.transition().attr("transform", "translate(" + translateX + "," + translateY + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
        d3.select(domNode).select('g.node').attr("transform", "translate(" + translateX + "," + translateY + ")");
        zoomListener.scale(zoomListener.scale());
        zoomListener.translate([translateX, translateY]);
        panTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            pan(domNode, speed, direction);
        }, 50);
    }
}

// Define the zoom function for the zoomable tree
function zoom() {
    baseSvg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

// define the zoomListener which calls the zoom function on the "zoom" event constrained within the scaleExtents
var zoomListener = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.1, 3]).on("zoom", zoom);

// Dragging function
function initiateDrag(d, domNode) {
    draggingNode = d;
    d3.select(domNode).select('.ghostCircle').attr('pointer-events', 'none');
    d3.selectAll('.ghostCircle').attr('class', 'ghostCircle show');
    d3.select(domNode).attr('class', 'node activeDrag');

    baseSvg.selectAll("g.node").sort(function(a, b) { // select the parent and sort the path's
        if (a.id != draggingNode.id) return 1; // a is not the hovered element, send "a" to the back
        else return -1; // a is the hovered element, bring "a" to the front
    });
    // if nodes has children, remove the links and nodes
    if (nodes.length > 1) {
        // remove link paths
        links = tree.links(nodes);
        nodePaths = baseSvg.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(links, function(d) {
            return d.target.id;
        }).remove();
        // remove child nodes
        nodesExit = baseSvg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function(d) {
            return d.id;
        }).filter(function(d, i) {
            if (d.id == draggingNode.id) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }).remove();
    }

    // remove parent link
    parentLink = tree.links(tree.nodes(draggingNode.parent));
    baseSvg.selectAll('path.link').filter(function(d, i) {
        if (d.target.id == draggingNode.id) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }).remove();

    dragStarted = null;
}

// Define the drag listeners for drag/drop behaviour of nodes.
dragListener = d3.behavior.drag()
.on("dragstart", function(d) {
    if (d == root) {
        return;
    }
    dragStarted = true;
    nodes = tree.nodes(d);
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
    // it's important that we suppress the mouseover event on the node being dragged. Otherwise it will absorb the mouseover event and the underlying node will not detect it d3.select(this).attr('pointer-events', 'none');
})
.on("drag", function(d) {
    if (d == root) {
        return;
    }
    if (dragStarted) {
        domNode = this;
        initiateDrag(d, domNode);
    }
    // get coords of mouseEvent relative to svg container to allow for panning
    relCoords = d3.mouse($('svg').get(0));
    if (relCoords[0] < panBoundary) {
        panTimer = true;
        pan(this, 'left');
    } else if (relCoords[0] > ($('svg').width() - panBoundary)) {

        panTimer = true;
        pan(this, 'right');
    } else if (relCoords[1] < panBoundary) {
        panTimer = true;
        pan(this, 'up');
    } else if (relCoords[1] > ($('svg').height() - panBoundary)) {
        panTimer = true;
        pan(this, 'down');
    } else {
        try {
            clearTimeout(panTimer);
        } catch (e) {

        }
    }

    d.x0 += d3.event.dy;
    d.y0 += d3.event.dx;

    var node = d3.select(this);
    node.attr("transform", "translate(" + d.y0 + "," + d.x0 + ")");
    updateTempConnector();
}).on("dragend", function(d) {
    if (d == root) {
        return;
    }                   
    domNode = this;
    if (selectedNode) {
        // now remove the element from the parent, and insert it into the new elements children
        var index = draggingNode.parent.children.indexOf(draggingNode);
        if (index > -1) {
            draggingNode.parent.children.splice(index, 1);
        }
        if (typeof selectedNode.children !== 'undefined' || typeof selectedNode._children !== 'undefined') {
            if (typeof selectedNode.children !== 'undefined') {
                selectedNode.children.push(draggingNode);
            } else {
                selectedNode._children.push(draggingNode);
            }
        } else {
            selectedNode.children = [];
            selectedNode.children.push(draggingNode);
        }
        // Make sure that the node being added to is expanded so user can see added node is correctly moved
        expand(selectedNode);
        sortTree();
        endDrag();
    } else {
        endDrag();
    }
});

function endDrag() {
    selectedNode = null;
    d3.selectAll('.ghostCircle').attr('class', 'ghostCircle');
    d3.select(domNode).attr('class', 'node');
    // now restore the mouseover event or we won't be able to drag a 2nd time
    d3.select(domNode).select('.ghostCircle').attr('pointer-events', '');
    updateTempConnector();
    if (draggingNode !== null) {
        update(root);
        //centerNode(draggingNode);
        draggingNode = null;
    }
}

// Helper functions for collapsing and expanding nodes.
function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
    }
}
function expand(d) {
    if (d._children) {
        d.children = d._children;
        d.children.forEach(expand);
        d._children = null;
    }
}

var overCircle = function(d) {
    selectedNode = d;
    updateTempConnector();
};
var outCircle = function(d) {
    selectedNode = null;
    updateTempConnector();
};

// Function to update the temporary connector indicating dragging affiliation
var updateTempConnector = function() {
    var data = [];
    if (draggingNode !== null && selectedNode !== null) {
        // have to flip the source coordinates since we did this for the existing connectors on the original tree
        data = [{
            source: {
                x: selectedNode.y0,
                y: selectedNode.x0
            },
            target: {
                x: draggingNode.y0,
                y: draggingNode.x0
            }
        }];
    }
    var link = baseSvg.selectAll(".templink").data(data);

    link.enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "templink")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.diagonal())
    .attr('pointer-events', 'none');

    link.attr("d", d3.svg.diagonal());

    link.exit().remove();
};

// Function to center node when clicked/dropped so node doesn't get lost when collapsing/moving with large amount of children.
function centerNode(source) {
    scale = zoomListener.scale();
    x = -source.y0;
    y = -source.x0;
    x = x * scale + viewerWidth / 2;
    y = y * scale + viewerHeight / 2;
    d3.select('g').transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
    zoomListener.scale(scale);
    zoomListener.translate([x, y]);
}

// Toggle children function
function toggleChildren(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } else if (d._children) {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    return d;
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
} 


function update(source) {
    // Compute the new height, function counts total children of root node and sets tree height accordingly.
    // This prevents the layout looking squashed when new nodes are made visible or looking sparse when nodes are removed
    // This makes the layout more consistent.

    var levelWidth = [1];
    var childCount = function(level, n) {

        if (n.children && n.children.length > 0) {
            if (levelWidth.length <= level + 1) levelWidth.push(0);

            levelWidth[level + 1] += n.children.length;
            n.children.forEach(function(d) {
                childCount(level + 1, d);
            });
        }
    };
    childCount(0, root);

    // Compute the new tree layout
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root),
        links = tree.links(nodes);

    // Set widths between levels based on maxLabelLength
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.y = (d.depth * (maxLabelLength * 10)); //maxLabelLength * 10px
        // alternatively to keep a fixed scale one can set a fixed depth per level
        // Normalize for fixed-depth by commenting out below line
        //d.y = (d.depth * 300); //500px per level.
    });

    // Update the nodes
    var node = baseSvg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .call(dragListener)
    .attr("class", "node")
    //.attr("transform", function(d) {
    //  return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    //})
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; })
    .on("click", click);

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr('class', 'nodeCircle')
    .attr("r", 1e-6)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "purple" : "#fff"; }); // color of a link depended on children having

    nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", 10) // distance of a name from a node
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .classed('nodeText white', true)
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    //.attr("transform", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "translate(0)" : "rotate(180)translate(-" + (d.name.length * 8.5)  + ")"; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // phantom node to give us mouseover in a radius around it
    nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr('class', 'ghostCircle')
    .attr("r", 50)
    .attr("opacity", 0.2) // change this to zero to hide the target area
    .style("fill", "white")
    .attr('pointer-events', 'mouseover')
    .on("mouseover", function(node) {
        overCircle(node);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(node) {
        outCircle(node);
    });

    // Update the text to reflect whether node has children or not.
    node.select('text')
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? (d.name.length * 5 + 15) : 10;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
    });

    // Change the circle fill depending on whether it has children and is collapsed
    node.select("circle.nodeCircle")
    .attr("r", 4.5)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "#111" : "#111"; // node color during toggle animation
    });

    // Transition nodes to their new position.
    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; })

    nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 4.5) // radius of a node circle
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "purple" : "#111"; }); // colors of node with collapsed and expanded children

    nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1) // 1 = 0% opacity
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "translate(0)" : "rotate(180)translate(-" + (d.name.length * 5 + 25)  + ")"; }); // rotate node names if more than 180 degrees and set before node -('node name' * 5 + 25)


    // TODO: appropriate transform
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    //.attr("transform", function(d) {
    //return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    //})
    //.attr("transform", function(d) { return "diagonal(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
    .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6);

    nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // Update the links…
    var link = baseSvg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
    });

    // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
    })
    .remove();

    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });
}

// Layout the tree initially and center on the root node.
update(root);
```

If somebody needs a whole program I can paste it another way.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but all your xs and ys are reversed.  Does this get you closer?  http://jsfiddle.net/t3yqdvtg/1/

Comment: Just drag a node and try to attach it to another but still do not drop. If you change between selected nodes you will see a wrong blue path which goes from source to target. When dragging, the nodes have invisible position which is proper for a horizontal tree, not a radial. I don't know how to change it.

Comment: Again, all your xs and ys are reversed throughout your code.   This is the root cause of your problems.  Did you do this on purpose?

Comment: What do you mean by xs and ys? Which coordinates are these?
If you're talking about these lines: 
data = [{
   source: {
      x: selectedNode.y0,
      y: selectedNode.x0
   },
   target: {
      x: draggingNode.y0,
      y: draggingNode.x0
   }
}];
When I reversed the x and y it just returned with a vertical tree logic, not horizontal.

Comment: Yes and in your dragging: `d.x0 += d3.event.dy; d.y0 += d3.event.dx; node.attr("transform", "translate(" + d.y0 + "," + d.x0 + ")");`, ys being added to xs, translations are backwards.  Now, suddenly your paths don't map correctly, don't you think this is the root cause?  What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: It is just a small mistake. You can change it in fiddle and everything is fine, like this:
`d.x0 += d3.event.dx;
    d.y0 += d3.event.dy;
    
    var node = d3.select(this);
    node.attr("transform", "translate(" + d.x0 + "," + d.y0 + ")");`
Look at the paths when dragging - they're going like if it was horizontal tree, not radial. The path from selected node and dragging node isn't correct.

Comment: That's what the link in my first comment fixed! Ha, ha...

Comment: But it's not the problem.